# MomentJS returning duplicate months?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using MomentJS to parse a Date String that I get from a service into a String month.

The String is formatted like "2013-1" Which should be January. Moment gets this correct.

However, something is weird once I get beyond August.

I have for example

```
console.log(moment('2012-9').format('MMMM'));
```

Which returns September for me.

Then I do:

```
console.log(moment('2012-10').format('MMMM')); it also returns September.
```

This eventually maps 11 to October and 12 to December, and thus an entire data set for the month of December is cutoff.

Am I doing something wrong with moment, or what could the issue be? I've checked all the other months and it does not do this.

Comment: I could not replicate this; http://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/1582/

Comment: Check this description of moment.js handling of strings.  Months start with 00 == January, 10 == September.  9 is an invalid month (depending on your browser). tested with moment 2.10.3

Comment: @nril When I do the same thing with console.log(moment('2012-0').format('MMMM')) it gives me an invalid date error.

Comment: @KimGysen This was what happened when I ran your fiddle: http://imgur.com/m26PhRh

Comment: My mistake - if you want to use this format you need provide format for the parsing the input - like this ('2012-01','YYYY-MM').  So your full statements would be:  console.log(moment('2012-09', "YYYY-MM").format('MMMM'));  In this format January is 01, not 00.

Comment: @OscarMcCullough The month is zero-indexed; when you run `console.log(moment().month(0).format("MMMM")); `, you will get January returned. However when you run `console.log(moment('2012-0').format('MM')); ` you will get undefined because the month is now 1-indexed. I guess that there is practical reason for this; I'm not sure why, but the library appears to deliver it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Edit** to anyone else facing the same problem:`moment('2012-10','YYYY-MM').format('MMMM');` solved the issue for OP

Which momentJS version are you using? I just tried with 2.10.5 and

```
console.log(moment('2012-9').format('MMMM'));//Returns September

console.log(moment('2012-10').format('MMMM'));//Returns October
```

Screenshot below is of the code running on the momentjs website in a console:

[image]

Upgrade to the latest version if you still face issues.

Comment: I'm using 2.10.0. I'll update and check what happens.

Comment: I updated to the latest version, here's the results in these two screenshots. One is the code of the line I used to check, the other is the result.

Line of code: http://i.imgur.com/dMTyWUi.png?1
Result: http://i.imgur.com/MKNIEms.png?1

Comment: I see, can you try with

console.log(moment('2012-10','YYYY-MM').format('MMMM'));  and reply with what you got?

Comment: @OscarMcCullough Glad that worked, can you accept the answer that helped you (other than your own)?

Answer (score 2):

I've determined the reason for this happening.

The format of the date, '2012-1' is not a standard ISO date.

To return the proper month when I work with the date, I have to specify the format my date string is in, so I use the

```
console.log(moment('2012-10', 'YYYY-M').format('MMMM'));
```

Which returns the correct month, October.

Thank you everyone for all the help.